# Search engine based on Google Spreadsheet

Tags: function, google-sheets

I am trying to create a Google search engine type function in Google Spreadsheets. I found this function in a Google forum, but it does not seem to work for me:

```
=iferror( filter(Data!A2:K; mmult( iferror(search(A1; Data!A2:K); A1 = ""); transpose(sign(column(Data!A2:K))) ) ); "(no matching data)" )
```

Comment: what are the symptoms of it not working? What does your data look like?

Comment: @Robin It shows "(no matching data)". I checked it again Data!A2:K does have the text that I enter in cell A1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment your formula is throwing an error because it is trying to perform a matrix multiplication with a boolean value (`A1=""`).
If you instead put 0 in the else clause of the iferror statement the filter function will evaluate 0 as false and everything else as true.

This has the drawback that you cannot filter for 0 as it will show the whole table but that's due to using mmult.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply Robin, I tried replacing space(" ") with "0" but still not working. I will share the woorkbook with you if you have a gmail account.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Robin